# Meshgraph of functions - Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure, mesh

Could someone please help me with this task; I was asked this question:

[image: question]

And I tried to solve it this way:

```
    syms x y

    [x,y]=meshgrid(0:0.-1:1);

    a=1-(exp(-x/sqrt(2))/2+exp(-x/sqrt(2)));

    b=exp(-x/sqrt(2))/((2+exp(-x/sqrt(2)))^2);

    c=((exp(-x/sqrt(2))*(exp(-x/sqrt(2))-2)))./4*((2+exp(-x/sqrt(2)))^3);

    d=(exp(-x/sqrt(2))*(((exp(-x/sqrt(2)))^2)-8*(exp(-x/sqrt(2)))+4))./24*((2+exp(-x/sqrt(2)))^4);

    z=a+(y*b)+(c*y^2)+(d*y^3);

    mesh(x,y,z);
```

but for some reason the graph won't plot, what seems to be the issue here?

Comment: "wont plot" - because you get an error? Or nothing happens? Or....

Comment: I'm guessing you get an error because `mesh` requires numeric data but you're inputting a symbolic function? Please copy-paste the full error message into your post so we have a chance of helping.

Comment: Try `fmesh`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fmesh.html

Comment: *1.* Please check the [`colon` operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) used inside the `meshgrid` function. *2.* Please check the brackets. Please check [operator precedence](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) documentation. *3.* Please read [Array vs Matrix Operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html)